# How to set per domain permissions on Google Cloud Domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I give users permission to manage a specific domain on Google Cloud Domains?

Ex:

- user1 is admin of user1.com
- user2 is admin of user2.com

PS: domains are on the same Project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the REST API to set the Access Control Policy. The CLI does not yet have the functionality.

[projects.locations.registrations.setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.registrations/setIamPolicy)

[Cloud Domains Permissions and Roles](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles)

Comment: Can you give me an example of a policy that would allow user1 to only be able to manage domain user1.com, but not user2.com?

Comment: @gfpacheco - On these forums, you show the work you did and we will try to help you. Asking for free coding is bad practice.

Comment: I know that, I only asked because I'm trying to do this for hours now and I think that can't be done. If you answered the question, I'm assuming you know how to do it. The "conditions" option offered by Google doesn't give me the flexibility to do what I want

Comment: Pasting links to the docs without really knowing if it can be done is also a bad practice in these forums

Comment: @gfpacheco I am a Google Cloud GDE and an expert with Google Domains and DNS. If you would have shown effort I would have helped you.

Comment: Congrats! And still, you don't know how to do it. So if I had started my question with "I've been searching for hours" or "I've tried everything" you'd have answered?

Comment: I answered your question. I provided a link to the API. It is up to you to write the code using that API. We do not write code for you. Keep insulting people, you will now find nobody will help you in the future.